# Rewrite Query without using correlated subqueries

Tags: oracle, performance, correlated-subquery

Using Oracle 10gR2 on LINUX, I'm trying to tune the following query.
I'm pretty sure that getting rid of the correlated subqueries and the possible use of some analytic functions may be the optimal way to go, but I'm just not getting it -- especially with the nested correlated subquery that selects on the MAX(TABLE_2.NOTE_DATE). Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT TABLE_4.INCIDENT_TYPE, 
   TABLE_4.POC_CONTACT, 
   (SELECT TABLE_2.NOTE_DATE 
           || ' ' 
           || TABLE_1.USER_FIRST_NAME 
           || ' ' 
           || TABLE_1.USER_LAST_NAME 
           || ' : ' 
           || TABLE_2.OTHER_HELP_NOTES 
    FROM   TABLE_1, 
           TABLE_2 
    WHERE  TABLE_2.USER_ID = TABLE_1.USER_ID 
           AND TABLE_2.REC_ID = TABLE_4.REC_ID 
           AND TABLE_2.NOTE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(TABLE_2.NOTE_DATE) 
                                              FROM   TABLE_2 
                                              WHERE  TABLE_2.REC_ID = TABLE_4.REC_ID 
                                                     AND TABLE_2.NOTE_DATE <= 
                                                         TABLE_4.REPORT_DATE)) 
                                                                 AS SUM_OF_SHORTAGE, 
   (SELECT TABLE_3.NOTE_DATE 
           || ' ' 
           || TABLE_1.USER_FIRST_NAME 
           || ' ' 
           || TABLE_1.USER_LAST_NAME 
           || ' : ' 
           || TABLE_3.HELP_NOTES 
    FROM   TABLE_1, 
           TABLE_3 
    WHERE  TABLE_3.USER_ID = TABLE_1.USER_ID 
           AND TABLE_3.REC_ID = TABLE_4.REC_ID 
           AND TABLE_3.NOTE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(TABLE_3.NOTE_DATE) 
                                                  FROM   TABLE_3 
                                                  WHERE  TABLE_3.REC_ID = TABLE_4.REC_ID 
                                                         AND TABLE_3.NOTE_DATE <= 
                                                             TABLE_4.REPORT_DATE)) AS HELP_NOTES, 
   TABLE_4.REPORT_NUM 
FROM   TABLE_4 
WHERE  TABLE_4.SITE_ID = '1';

@C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\CLIENT_1\RDBMS\ADMIN\UTLXPLS.SQL;

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
PLAN HASH VALUE: 4036328474                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                 
| ID  | OPERATION                     | NAME                       | ROWS  | BYTES | COST (%CPU)| TIME     |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                            | 13009 |  2286K|   449   (2)| 00:00:06 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  1 |  FILTER                       |                            |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |                            |     3 |   612 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_2                    |     3 |   552 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IX_TABLE_2_REC_ID          |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_1                    |     1 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  6 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | TABLE_1_PK                 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|   7 |   SORT AGGREGATE              |                            |     1 |    13 |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  8 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_2                    |     1 |    13 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|*  9 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IX_TABLE_2_REC_ID          |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|* 10 |  FILTER                       |                            |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|* 11 |   HASH JOIN                   |                            |    17 |  4063 |   482   (2)| 00:00:06 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|* 12 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLE_3                    |    17 |  3723 |   474   (2)| 00:00:06 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|  13 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLE_1                    |  1504 | 30080 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|  14 |   SORT AGGREGATE              |                            |     1 |    13 |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|* 15 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLE_3                    |     1 |    13 |   474   (2)| 00:00:06 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
|* 16 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL            | TABLE_4                    | 13009 |  2286K|   449   (2)| 00:00:06 |                                                                                                                                                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                 

PREDICATE INFORMATION (IDENTIFIED BY OPERATION ID):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   1 - FILTER("TABLE_2"."NOTE_DATE"= (SELECT /*+ */ MAX("TABLE_2"."NOTE_DATE")                                                                                                                                                                                                           
              FROM "TABLE_2" "TABLE_2" WHERE "TABLE_2"."REC_ID"=:B1 AND                                                                                                                                                                                                        
              "TABLE_2"."NOTE_DATE"<=:B2))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   4 - ACCESS("TABLE_2"."REC_ID"=:B1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   6 - ACCESS("TABLE_2"."USER_ID"="TABLE_1"."USER_ID")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   8 - FILTER("TABLE_2"."NOTE_DATE"<=:B1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   9 - ACCESS("TABLE_2"."REC_ID"=:B1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  10 - FILTER("TABLE_3"."NOTE_DATE"= (SELECT /*+ */                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
              MAX("TABLE_3"."NOTE_DATE") FROM "TABLE_3" "TABLE_3" WHERE                                                                                                                                                                                            
              "TABLE_3"."REC_ID"=:B1 AND "TABLE_3"."NOTE_DATE"<=:B2))                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  11 - ACCESS("TABLE_3"."USER_ID"="TABLE_1"."USER_ID")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  12 - FILTER("TABLE_3"."REC_ID"=:B1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  15 - FILTER("TABLE_3"."REC_ID"=:B1 AND "TABLE_3"."NOTE_DATE"<=:B2)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  16 - FILTER("TABLE_4"."SITE_ID"=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 41 ROWS SELECTED
```

Breaking down this query -- the key problem seems to be the following:

```
select REC_ID, TO_CHAR(REPORT_DATE,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') REPORT_DATE,  
(SELECT MAX(TABLE_2.note_date) as MAX_DATE
FROM   TABLE_2 
where  TABLE_2.REC_ID = TABLE_1.REC_ID 
       and TABLE_2.NOTE_DATE <= TABLE_1.REPORT_DATE
) NOTES_MAX_DATE
from TABLE_1 where REC_ID = 121 order by TO_DATE(REPORT_DATE,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS');
```

Which should return the following:

```
    REC_ID                 REPORT_DATE        NOTES_MAX_DATE                          
---------------------- ------------------ ------------------------- 
121                    17-APR-10 12:30:00                           
121                    24-APR-10 12:30:00                           
121                    01-MAY-10 12:30:00                           
121                    08-MAY-10 12:30:00                           
121                    15-MAY-10 12:30:00 12-MAY-10                 
121                    22-MAY-10 12:30:01 17-MAY-10                 
121                    29-MAY-10 12:30:01 25-MAY-10                 
121                    05-JUN-10 12:30:00 25-MAY-10                 
 8 rows selected
```

The output needs to be the same as the above.  I tried creating a join as follows:

```
SELECT TABLE_1.REC_ID, TO_CHAR(TABLE_1.REPORT_DATE,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') REPORT_DATE, MAX(TABLE_2.NOTE_DATE) AS NOTES_MAX_DATE
     FROM   TABLE_2, 
            TABLE_1 
     where  TABLE_2.REC_ID = TABLE_1.REC_ID
            AND TABLE_2.NOTE_DATE <= TABLE_1.REPORT_DATE 
            and ( TABLE_1.SITE_ID = '1' ) 
            and TABLE_1.REC_ID = 121
     group  by TABLE_1.REC_ID, TABLE_1.REPORT_DATE
     order by TO_DATE(REPORT_DATE,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS');
```

But that yields:

```
    REC_ID                 REPORT_DATE        NOTES_MAX_DATE        
---------------------- ------------------ ------------------------- 
121                    15-MAY-10 12:30:00 12-MAY-10                 
121                    22-MAY-10 12:30:01 17-MAY-10                 
121                    29-MAY-10 12:30:01 25-MAY-10                 
121                    05-JUN-10 12:30:00 25-MAY-10
```

So I'm really stumped.  Any ideas? -- Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a version that  <strike>only gets the `max` once and</strike>  should remove the correlated sub-queries. It does still use sub-queries, but, as they're in the `FROM` clause rather than the `SELECT` clause, the database should do a better job of resolving them. It's probably possible to remove those sub-queries as well, but it's more readable this way. This version also uses the SQL-99 syntax for joins, which is generally considered preferable.

```
SELECT table_4.incident_type, 
       table_4.poc_contact, 
       t2.sum_of_shortage, 
       t3.help_notes, 
       table_4.report_num
FROM             table_4
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT table_2.rec_id,
                         table_2.note_date
                         || ' '
                         || table_1.user_first_name
                         || ' '
                         || table_1.user_last_name
                         || ' : '
                         || table_2.other_help_notes
                            AS sum_of_shortage
                  FROM   table_1 
                    JOIN table_2 
                      ON table_2.user_id = table_1.user_id
                  WHERE  table_2.note_date =
                            (SELECT MAX(table_2.note_date) AS max_date
                             FROM   table_2
                             WHERE  table_2.rec_id = table_4.rec_id 
                                AND table_2.note_date <= table_4.report_date)) t2
              ON t2.rec_id = table_4.rec_id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT table_3.rec_id,
                         table_3.note_date
                         || ' '
                         || table_1.user_first_name
                         || ' '
                         || table_1.user_last_name
                         || ' : '
                         || table_3.other_help_notes
                            AS help_notes
                  FROM   table_1 
                    JOIN table_3 
                      ON table_3.user_id = table_1.user_id
                  WHERE  table_2.note_date =
                            (SELECT MAX(table_3.note_date) AS max_date
                             FROM   table_3
                             WHERE  table_3.rec_id = table_4.rec_id 
                                AND table_3.note_date <= table_4.report_date)) t3
              ON t3.rec_id = table_4.rec_id
WHERE  table_4.site_id = '1';
```

---

@shawno: You're right, the `with` clause was flawed because I misread your initial query. Above is a corrected version. Because the `max` values are specific to each row, the method that you were already using to get those values is probably the most efficient. Your best option for optimizing this appears to just be moving the sub-queries from the `select` clause to the `from` clause.

Also, this is an untested solution, as I have neither your table structure nor your data. The best I can do without putting far too much work into it is to verified that the syntax is valid.

Comment: +1 for the SQL-99 syntax. IMHO nobody should still be using the old SQL-86 syntax any more.

Comment: @Oliie - there are sound reasons for still choosing the old syntax rather than the ANSI syntax.  As an example, check out this detailed blog post from Jonathan Lewis: http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/ansi-argh/

Comment: Thanks for your help.  However, I don't see how your solution works -- shouldn't you also reference table_4 in the with clause? If i don't then I get an ORA-00904 error - invalid identifier. Also, it seems like that would only produce the max date for all the dates in table_3.note_date (i.e. returns only a single date).  I need the max date for every rec_id in table 4 that equals a rec_id in table_3 (where there are many of the same rec_id's, but I only want to match up against the ones with the max date).  That's why there is that nested correlated subquery to find the max date.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I see in the WITH clause you considered tables 3 and 4 for the max date (from the second nested correlated subquery), but what about tables 2 and 4 (from the first nested correlated subquery?  I see you join that  as "MD", but it seems that for at least one of the INNER JOINS (the first one) that we are now comparing the wrong set of max dates.

Comment: Thanks for trying -- your latest version doesn't work either; since we're referencing TABLE_4 within the (SELECT MAX(...) correlated subqueries then there needs to be a reference to TABLE_4 in the outer query just above.  And there isn't so we get the ORA-00904 invalid identifier error again. :(

Comment: I added some addition notes and actions I've tried above in the original question.